# Need Isanchor yes using xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, category

How to isAnchor is yes using layout xml file.option is available yes in admin  but i have 200+ category so it is possible xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an external php file in root....

```
 <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');

        // Load Up Magento Core
        define('MAGENTO', realpath('/'));

        require_once(MAGENTO . 'app/Mage.php');

        $app = Mage::app();

        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('is_anchor', 0)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 1))
         ->setOrder('entity_id');

        foreach($categories as $category) {

         echo $category->getId() . "\t" . $category->getName() . "\n";

         $category->setIsAnchor(1);

         $category->save();

        }

?>
```

Comment: not working this solution Please read once again  my question.

Comment: Hi @Jigar_vala  are you using an external file to make this fix or any inside files